# app.config or TXT/INI for saving config options?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I'm working on a application where users should be define a output directory. After read a lot about **app.config** and also about **ini** ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file) says it's not recommended and .NET hasn't any class or namespace to read them)  and **txt** (is a bit tedious) I decide to go to app.config. So I wrote this code:

```
    // Here I save to app.config file
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            oConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Add("directorio_bases", textBox2.Text);
            oConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
            textBox1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["directorio_bases"];
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debes seleccionar una ruta donde guardar las bases generadas", "Error",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }

    // Here I read from app.config file just for informative purpose only
    private void ConfigurationUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["directorio_bases"];
    }

    // Here is where I get the path to the folder
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox2.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
```

And the code works fine during program execution but when I close/open the program values get lost. So my question is:

- what I'm doing wrong? I mean why values aren't keep?
- Did yours use app.config, config.ini or config.txt file? I'll need to ear your opinions about this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to manually run the executable (e.g. from the bin folder)?
If you are running the application in debug mode the app.config file is not modified.

Please have a look at the following link:
[C# - app config doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490470/c-sharp-app-config-doesnt-change)