# App config windows form application

Tags: c#, app-config

I just published my windows form application(via `Build -> Publish Application`) and I told the setup to save it in a map. Now the map contains this:

```
 Application Files(folder) -> sync_1_0_0_4(folder) -> sync.application
 Setup.exe                                            sync.exe.config.deploy
 sync.application                                     sync.exe.deploy
                                                      sync.exe.manifest
```

And some DLLs. Now I want to change a key from the app config, so the most logical thing to do is to open the `sync.exe.config.deploy`. As I do I see my app config lines just perfectly normal, so I make the desired changes and I run my application. The problem is, nothing has changed in my application. Am I forgetting something? This is my first time publishing a C# application. I've tried this answer: [C# - app config doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490470/c-sharp-app-config-doesnt-change?rq=1) but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you redeploy it? The changes in sync.exe.config.deploy will probably not take effect until your next deployment.

Comment: Each time you compile the "App.config" file is copied to your output directory as "YourApplication.exe.config". If you want permanent changes, change it in the app.config

Comment: @Tobberoth Yes I did.

Comment: Don't think you can change the sync.exe.config if you used click once deployment. The manifest will contain a hash of the config. If you change it you must change the manifest aswell or the program won't start up with a "tampered" message

Comment: @MarvinSmit Sorry, I dont get that. What do you mean? What should I change in the manifest?

Comment: Since you used "Publish", it's is a click once application. This will contain your application, but also an XML file which contains information about the program when you published it (including hashes). This file is used on startup of your application to validate no 'hacking' modifications where done. So hashes are compared.

Comment: @MarvinSmit So how to fix? I cant find anything usefull in the manifest

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41187/discussion-between-marvin-smit-and-loko)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClickOnce publication does a lot of things. For one, it does cryptographic verification that files haven't changed, so you can't just edit those files. It also copies all deployment files to somewhere on the user's hard drive, and if the app is not reinstalled, and the version doesn't change, then nothing will be copied. And third, if your settings are user scoped, they may have been changed by the user already and won't be reread from the new app config.

Long story short, if you have to change the config, then you have to redeploy, and make sure your settings are application scoped, not user scoped.

Comment: Aha then ClickOnce isn't what I need. Thank you

Comment: I usually just copy the bin\debug or bin\release folder of my application to some clients, they don't need fancy setup programs and it just works. But for example when yo have to provide your app to hundreds of users from a website and make sure it is kept up to date automatically, then ClickOnce is the way to go.

Comment: Yup someone just explained to me in chat :D Got it working now